# How to visualize Zend_Search_Lucene documents?

Tags: php, database, lucene

Is there a phpmyadmin type backend available?  Or should I just build a custom solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

[Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) is a great tool for getting a nice front-end on a Lucene index, and is very easy to use and setup.

I've also used [LIMO](http://limo.sourceforge.net/), for a web-based toolkit.